# Changing language direction from LTR to RTL based on language change

Tags: yii, yii2

I have this code when I want to change the direction of language from left to right and according to language change in Yii 1.1.16

```
<html <?php if(Yii::app()->language == 'ar')  echo "dir='rtl'"; ?> >
```

How could I apply this code in Yii2?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved ii, could help someone

```
<?php
$dir_ar = "dir='rtl'";
$dir_en = "dir='ltr'";
?>

<html lang="<?php Yii::$app->language?>"
    <?php
    if(Yii::$app->language=='ar')
       echo $dir_ar;
    ?>
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `app()` with `$app` like that: `Yii::$app->language`.

See official documentation for [language](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$language-detail).